# Reverse Cell Values Order in Python-docx Tables

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm using the python-docx library to work with Word documents, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to fill cells in tables.

Specifically, I'm trying to insert values into cells in a table, and I'm facing a problem where the order of values is reversed in all but the first table.

Here's the relevant part of my Python code:

```
# From right to left becouse text is in Hebrew
  table.cell(0, 5).text = "text 1"
  table.cell(0, 4).text = "text 2"
  table.cell(0, 3).text = "text 3"
  table.cell(0, 2).text = "text 4"
  table.cell(0, 1).text = "text 5"
  table.cell(0, 0).text = "text 6"
```

I have the same exact problem in this code :

```
# Start at row 5 because we need to leave space for the 5 default rows
    for row in range(5, len(docx_table.rows) + 1):
        for column in range(1, 7):  # Columns 1 to 7 in the excel
            cell = nz_xl.cell((int(xl_row) + row) + 5, column + 1) 
            # 'row + 5' because don't need to copy the first 2 rows
            if cell.value is not None:
                docx_table.cell(row, column - 1).text = str(cell.value)
                # 'column - 1' because the table starts at 1 and not at 0. Otherwise 'index out of range'
```

The issue I'm facing is that this code works correctly for the first table but reverses the order of values in all subsequent tables. How can I ensure that the values are inserted correctly in all tables?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it with non Hebrew document?

Comment: Could you try to demonstrate your problem with an [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

> Not an answer, but doesn't fit as a comment and hopefully moves you a step or two along:

Sorry Daniel, your code isn't fitting inside my head. I recommend you extract all the Excel bits etc., just create a few lists of words, and try inserting that in reverse order. Putting all those bits together in one function makes this so complex a reader (including yourself) can't easily reason about what it's doing. This gives bugs a place to hide. Here's a simple example, maybe you can replace the words with Hebrew words and give it a try:

```py
data = [
    ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
    ["jkl", "mno", "pqr"],
]

col_count = 3  # -- or len(data[0]) maybe --
row_count = len(data)
target_row_idxs = range(row_count)

for row_idx in target_row_idxs:
    row = docx_table.rows[row_idx]
    data_row = data[row_idx]
    for col_idx in range(col_count):              # -- counts 0, 1, 2
        target_col_idx = col_count - col_idx - 1  # -- counts 2, 1, 0
        row.cells[target_col_idx].text = data_row[col_idx]
```

A couple points to draw your attention to:

- Extract things out of the "loop" code to simplify it as much as possible and give it a name that helps make sense of it. An expression like `range(5, len(docx_table.rows) + 1)` is a good example, perhaps it could be named something like `target_row_idxs` to make it clear what it is.
- Especially when working with things like rows and columns, be precise in your naming. Don't call a "row index" `row`, for example. Reserve that name for an actual `Row` object. Same thing with using `cols` for `col_count` for example.

Once you start extracting out some "components" and making the loop as simple a "composition" of those elements, I expect you'll suddenly see it start working. If not, then at least you'll have a clear case that someone can understand well enough to help you find where you went wrong :)